# No service for type Identity.UserManager when using multiple identity users

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, roles

**My setup**

Currently, I have two models that inherit from `ApplicationUser`, which inherits `IdentityUser`. The user classes are:

```
public abstract class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [PersonalData]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}

public class StudentUser : ApplicationUser
{
    [PersonalData]
    [Required]
    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }

    // A user belongs to one group
    public Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeUser : ApplicationUser { }
```

The `ApplicationUser` contains *shared* properties, like the First and Last name. Both `StudentUser` and `EmployeeUser` have their **own** properties and relationships. This structure follows the [Table Per Hierarchy (TPH)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-2.0#options-for-mapping-inheritance-to-database-tables) inheritance.

Ideally, I want to follow the [Table Per Type (TPT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-2.0#options-for-mapping-inheritance-to-database-tables) inheritance, because the SQL structure is better. ASP.NET Core only supports TPH natively, so that is why I follow the TPT approach.

**The problem**

I added the Identity service in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

When I call `UserManager<StudentUser>` or `UserManager<EmployeeUser>`, I get the following error:

> No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[ClassroomMonitor.Models.StudentUser]' has been registered.

**My question**

Unfortunately, I can't find much about this error combined with this implementation.

Is it (even) possible to make it work this way?

Any help or thoughts are welcome.

**Update 1**

Manually adding the `StudentUser` or `EmployeeUser` as a scoped services does not seem to work (mentioned as the first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52698155/3625118)).

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
// or..
services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

This throws the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore1[ClassroomMonitor.Models.StudentUser]'

**Update 2**

Here is a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/94a55df9d4df35f2fb6596b54dedff25) to give you a better picture of the project structue:

Comment: Show the definitions of the user classes. The same way you created derived user classes you would also need to create derived user managers.

Comment: @Nkosi I've provided them now.

Comment: Have you tried registering identity for each user type, but using the same Db context?

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Why do you need to initiate seperate UserManagers at all for derived types? I work with this scenario using the UserManager<ApplicationUser> for inserting or fetching both the Employee and Student users

Comment: Well, both roles have their own properties. An employee does not have a StudentNumber.

Comment: It would be easier if you provide a gist with minimal complete sample project which reproduces the issue

Comment: @IvanStoev Good point. I've added a gist.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ideally you would call the same identity setup for the derived user types as for the base user type.

Unfortunately [`AddIdentity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentity?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method contains some code that prevents of using it more than once.

Instead, you could use [`AddIdentityCore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.identityservicecollectionextensions.addidentitycore?view=aspnetcore-2.1). The role services are already registered by the `AddIdentity`, the only difference is that `AddIdentityCore` registers `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser>`, so in order to match `AddIdentity` setup it needs to be replaced with `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser, TRole>` via [`AddClaimsPrincipalFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilder.addclaimsprincipalfactory?view=aspnetcore-2.1) method.

The code looks like something like this:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();

services.AddIdentityCore<StudentUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<StudentUser, IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();

services.AddIdentityCore<EmployeeUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<EmployeeUser, IdentityRole>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI();
```

Of course you could move the common parts in a custom extension methods.

**Update:** Although the role services are already configured, you still need to call `AddRoles` in order to set correctly the `Role` property of the `IndentityBuilder`, which then is used by the `AddEntityFrameworkStores`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately your solution results in a `NotSupportedException: Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>.`

Comment: @Matthijs Darn identity, the register and login was working :-( See the update, now it should work.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to do the job :-) I hope Microsoft will document this somewhere.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you very much! I've been all over the ms docs trying to find the best approach to this design and didn't find a single topic about this, it's weird that they didn't document a very common scenario.

Comment: By the way we're dealing with same problem now, too . How did you handle controller side of more than one usermanagement usage? Did you use like below in controller constructor : UserManager<StudentUser> userManager , UserManager<EmployeeUser> userManager2 etc. How did you solve usermanager and userstore usage of different types in code ? Could you use generic type because we couldn't.

Comment: @slnkykrn You have to use concrete services - `UserManager<StudentUser>`, `UserManager<EmployeeUser>` etc. because neither `UserManager<TUser>` class nor `IUserStpre<TUser>` interface support variance. You could eventually use generic `UserManager<TUser> where TUser : ApplicationUser` in case the controllers have common generic base with the same generic type argument and constraint. But still they have to be concrete because of the forementioned reason - `UserManager<EmployeeUser>` cannot be treated polymorphically as `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you @IvanStoev after commented here I created  an issue about this could you please share your opinion also there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64964545/how-can-we-handle-more-than-one-user-usage-for-identity-core-usermanagement-and

Answer (score 2):

Tested on fresh project:

> dotnet new mvc --auth Individual

Startup.cshtml

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

User.cs

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Test { get; set; }
}
```

**Probably here's your problem:**

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
```

---

Also tested this way:

Startup.cs

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User2>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Users.cs

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string TestA { get; set; }
}
public class User2 : User
{
    public string TestB { get; set; }
}
```

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@inject SignInManager<User2> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User2> UserManager
```

Comment: That works if I register one user class. Like: User2. But I want to be able to use both.

Comment: @Matthijs Well, I've no idea. I'd suggest workaround like not using inheritance but something like that ``User.Role = Student`` instead.

Comment: That could be a workaround, yes. But it _should_ be possible somehow, because other answers on Stack recommend this way. I found another workaround for my situation, but I'll keep this question/bounty open for other user inputs. Thanks for thinking with me, though!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing register DI for it.

```
services.AddScoped<UserManager<AppUser>, UserManager<AppUser>>()
```

StudentUser and EmployeeUser are similar to it

Comment: This gives the following error: `InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IUserStore`1[ClassroomMonitor.Models.StudentUser]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[ClassroomMonitor.Models.StudentUser]'.`

I had to change it to individual lines as well.

Comment: did you register enough `services.AddScoped<UserManager<ApplicationUser>, UserManager<AppicationUser>>()`
`services.AddScoped<UserManager<StudentUser>, UserManager<StudentUser>>()`
`services.AddScoped<UserManager<EmployeeUser>, UserManager<EmployeeUser>>()`

Comment: Yes, I did, but that results in the error (first comment)

Comment: Did you use StudentSore? if you have, please try this
`services.AddScoped<IUserStore<StudentUser>, StudentUserStore>()`

Comment: I don't use any custom storage.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add scoped for the different user types, you should really not have many different types which are derived from IdentityUser as it will mean you will either have incorrect types used all over the place or multiple different user tables in the database.

you should really structure your data so it has an `ApplicationUser` which is referenced by the employee entity (a separate entity) or the Student entity (again a separate entity).
there is more of a design issue here rather than a code issue.

ASPIdentity will inject the `Usermanager<ApplicationUser>` when you `AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>`, so adding more user managers will not work as expected.

**The answer**
 you must create  different entities for every type of user, 1 for student, 1 for employee, etc. these will all have a Foreign Key to the user's id, and that will enable you to add multiple types of user without the need for different tables per user type.

then when you `addIdentity` you can register `ApplicationUser` (as is at the moment) then inject `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` which will get the user type.

Answer (score 0):

if core>=3.0

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<WorldContext>();
```